# Ext JS undefined .getRecord() on form

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a form and I need some field value on the fly.

When I go on the browser console, I can get the element:

```
var temp = Ext.ComponetQuery.query('#the_element')[0]
temp.getForm().getRecord()
```

And it works. Nice.

But, when I have to get the element in my code using

```
this.up('form').getForm().getRecord()
```

or

```
Ext.ComponetQuery.query('#the_element')[0].getForm().getRecord()
```

then the record of the element form has gone away.

```
undefined
```

A think (maybe a was right) that DOM haven't display his markup yet.

I am trying to get the element in the `render` or `afterrender` events.

So, what do I have to do?

```
  i {owner: i, checkValidityTask: Ext.util.DelayedTask, checkDirtyTask: Ext.util.DelayedTask, 
   > _boundItems: i
   > _record: i
      >  data: Object
```

Comment: Is your `this.up('form').getForm().getRecord()` call inside of a function?

Comment: listeners: {

                            render: {

                                fn: function (eOpts) {

                                    var formPanel = this.up('form');
                                    var form = formPanel.getForm();


                                    console.log(form.getRecord());

Comment: yes, it's inside of a function

Comment: I can see him on the inspect element like : _record, there is all your values, but on the code , record appears undefined

Comment: Have solution , thanks.

Once i call the form from a grid, and the grid has the value that i want, i'll set this value

as a form param, and call into my function by:

var formPanel = this.up('form');

console.log(formPanel.my_setted_param_from_grid)

Comment: Why don't you add and accept that as the answer to your question. (SO encourages users to post answers to their own questions.)

Comment: Cause stackoverflow stopped me when i was do this :/  - no reputation enough. They tell me:

Comment: "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking."